# How to replicate ffmpeg filter during Adobe Premiere Pro 2022 export (to speed up the video without pitch distortion)

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, premiere-pro

My normal process is to export a project to mp4 and then use ffmpeg to speed up the video like [this](https://superuser.com/a/611927/74576):

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/1.3[v];[0:a]atempo=1.3[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

It's super annoying for this to be 2 steps, which become especially time-consuming for long videos.

Is there a way to tell Premiere to do this during the original export?

Comment: Looks like you want a simpler version of this: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/21997/

Comment: @Gyan Yeah, maybe there is an easy way to select all clips on all tracks of a project and apply one "filter" that speeds them up while maintaining the original pitch of any associated audio).